# FetchMode as JOIN in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How do we specify `FetchMode` as `JOIN` in JPA? I do understand that in hibernate we can do it by `@Fetch(FetchType.JOIN)`. But how do we achieve this in JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Use the hibernate-specific annotation.